# Git GC clean while files are in use

Tags: c#, git, garbage-collection

I have an app that runs constantly and collect about 200 gb of data in the GC per day, so I need to manually delete it everyday , but as the app is constantly running I can make this automatically happen at ex. 3:00 AM. 
I did this ,but as long as the app is using the files it wont let me clean the GC, the problem comes from that, that I cant be sure what exactly at this moment is using the files. Is there a way to force git clean its GC without taking in mind if anything is using this files , or the error is coming from windows that is not letting it to delete the used files ?

Comment: Check this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Comment: Is your program creating git objects?

Comment: Well it triggers git pulls trough a program , so I believe it does. 
 user1845593 - thanks for suggestion , but I cant do that as there are too many files and I do not know which ones will exactly gc clean, I guess the only way is to stop the program and clean em with another 1 , which will be bad ,but cant think of another option